# Handle Future[User] in Deadbolt's getSubject

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, deadbolt

Is there a way in Deadbolt to use Future[User] in MyDeadboltHandler's getSubject method without blocking?

Current method expects a request and returns an Option[Subject]

```
override def getSubject[A](request: Request[A]): Option[Subject] = {
  currentUser //<-- currentUser is a Future[User] 
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make this change for the next release of Deadbolt.

Update: Version 2.3.2 of Deadbolt now gives you...
Scala: Future[Option[Subject]]
Java: F.Promise

Additionally, this version is available via Maven Central so you don't need to specify the Objectify Repository resolver any more.  Older versions still require the resolver.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can map a `Future[A]` to an `Option[B]` without first waiting for the `Future` to complete. Whatever is calling `getSubject` knows it's a synchronous call, and thus will wait for the `Option[Subject]` whether you use `Future`s within it or not.

```
override def getSubject[A](request: Request[A]): Option[Subject] = {
    val user = Await.result(currentUser, Duration.Inf) // Or whatever Duration you deem appropriate
    ....
}
```

Comment: You are totally right. However, I was hoping to find something in dealbolt features; like an alternative getSubject method which directly works with futures. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Matwell After looking through the source, no. There's nothing apparent.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this is by downloading the source code and then modify it to return a future. I did that, but then decided it was better not to do this, because I would hit the database on each request, even when it wouldn't be necessary. My solution is to store enough data in the session to authorise the user.

Of cause this depends on how much security your application needs? In my case it is sufficient to handle it in the business logic.

Comment: Did you ever consider using play cache to avoid hitting the db on each request? Any problems with that?

Comment: That would be more of a quick fix. Since we are still going to hit the database on the request thread. Not a problem if we have few users, but a problem if we have many, since we would hit the database more and more, as the cache expires.

I ended up simple storing enough data in the session to regenerate the permissions, and then always double check in the backend code. However I'm now using my own solution rather then Deadbolt.